# Opening an app and a .shy work, but a packaged app gives a window with only button?

Tags: shoes

I coded a Shoes app that works flawlessly when opening the .rb file through Shoes or packaging it into a .shy file, but when I package it into a Windows executable whether using my cached Win32 binaries or redownloading them the .exe just brings up this window:

[image]

Any way to fix this or to compile it differently as an executable?

Running Ruby 1.9.3 and Shoes 3.2 on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that .shy executable only packages a script, not the whole directory, you can bypass such problem by creating environment variables in which you can save your directory path and access it from .shy to run your app properly. I'm not sure will this help you as it took so long for anybody to answer. If you don't know how to set up environment variables let me know so I'll post my solution.